# Check redshift cluster status programmatically

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there any way to ping redshift cluster and get its status. in JAVA, if it is "available" or not. I have to ping a cluster during downtime and check if it is available or not.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you define "available".

The [`DescribeClusters()`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/redshift/RedshiftClient.html#describeClusters--) API call returns a [`ClusterStatus`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/redshift/model/Cluster.html#clusterStatus--) that provides the cluster status from the AWS viewpoint.

Or, you could connect to the Redshift cluster with an SQL client and see whether it accepts the connection. That would be checking the status from whether Redshift itself is responsive.

If the 'downtime' you report also affects the ClusterStatus, then the API call would be the easier method.

Comment: I did it using this code                                                                                                           
        "AmazonRedshift client = AmazonRedshiftClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).withRegion(region).build();

            DescribeClustersResult result = client.describeClusters(new DescribeClustersRequest().withClusterIdentifier(clusterIdentifier));"     Sorry for bad format